# German equivalent of the english "of"

Tags: preposition

I was considering this sentence:

> Der Dschungel is die Heimat einer Vielzahl exotischer Tierarten

Now, I was thinking, if I was to write the English equivalent:

> **The Jungle is the habitat of a countless number of exotic species**

Directly translated:

> The Jungle is the habitat a countless number exotic species.

Sometimes, in German, I have seen the dative case to fill in the English preposition "of" equivalent for possession.

I also understand English and German do not respect a 1:1 translation, which makes sense.

But, in the example above, is the preposition "of" not existent in German. How does it work?

Comment: Just to make sure there's no confusion, because you mention "dative": In isolation, the phrase "einer Vielzahl exotischer Tierarten" could be either in dative or in genitive, but in this particular case, it *cannot* be dative. It's the genitive that replaces "von", and that's probably also what you've seen before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Der Dschungel is**t** die Heimat einer Vielzahl exotischer Tierarten.

A "literal" English translation is:

*The jungle is the exotic animals' countless number's home.*

German speakers use these genitive supplements excessively, at least in writing. It's also a sign of educated speech. In some dialects, you instead hear

> Der Dschungel ist die Heimat **von** einer Vielzahl **von** exotische**n** Tierarten.

which resembles the English sentence. Sometimes, only one prepositional object is replaced by a genitive supplement.

Answer (score 1):

In German, the genitive case is used to express the *of*:

> ... ein**er** Vielzahl tropisch**er** Tierarten.

As there are no visible cases in English you need a preposition to express this meaning, except for cases like *my teacher's name* = *der Name mein**es** Lehrers / mein**er** Lehrerin.*

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment. Instead of a preposition you use declension - not only of articles, but also adjectives and nouns.

Comment: my apologies but I meant declination of articles!